# Moving artifact from Gitlab CI to project Wiki page

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, asciidoc, swagger-maven-plugin

I'm setting up Gitlab CI to create an asciidoc page from a Swagger YAML specification.

To this end, I've set up Gitlab to execute the swagger maven plugin and save the results to the public artifacts folder, like this:

```
enter codedeploy:jdk8:
stage: test
script:
- 'mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS swagger2markup:convertSwagger2markup'
#only:
#  - master
# Archive up the built documentation site.
artifacts:
paths:
- target/asciidoc
image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

pages:
image: busybox:latest
stage: deploy
script:
 - mv target/asciidoc public
dependencies:
 - deploy:jdk8
artifacts:
 paths:
 - public
#only:
#  - master
```

My question is how to automatically upload the resulting asciidoc artifacts as wiki pages in my Gitlab project. I can browse the public artifacts folder but Gitlab doesn't render the .adoc files in there, it only offers to download them.

**Update**. I found [Gitlab issue 18106](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18106) which is a feature request to "allow runners to push via their CI token". I think this feature would be the answer to my question, or does anyone have a better idea?